# firebase-admin createUser with random password or default undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

After a user subscribes to my Saas product, I am creating the user in firebase using `firebase-admin`. I noticed the `firebase` web SDK has `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` whereas `firebase-admin` has only `createUser`. So I want to confirm I'm creating this correctly.

Currently I have the following code to create users and I send them a `passwordResetLink` after. **Will this create a email/password account correctly or should I be initializing with a random password?**

Note: The providerId for these new users becomes `'password'` after they click the password reset link and set one, but until then they don't have a provider.

```
const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email,
    emailVerified: false,
    // phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
    // password: "secretPassword", // do I need this to initialize the user correctly or can I leave it undefined?
    displayName,
    // photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
    disabled: false,
  })
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "The providerId for these new users is 'password' so if that's default for user/password accounts, that would answer my question."? Actually, if we execute your code, a user is created **without** provider.

Comment: You're correct @RenaudTarnec I didn't realize I clicked the reset password link on my dummy data I was using to make this question. Thank you for clarifying and leading to the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated from @Renaud, you don't actually have a providerId until you add a password with a reset link, so it seems that it would be recommended that you would want to initialize with a random password so that it will populate the provider with a typical email/password login

Comment: If you only activate the user name/password provider, I think you can just let the password empty. As you said, after the password reset the provider will be set. I didn’t test all possible side effects however.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I agree with your assessment, because I don't know the possible side effects I feel it's appropriate to start off with a randomized password. But leaving it as is with an empty password field with a reset link gets to the same place